# How to add image in image view ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have a view controller,on top of this I have added a image view.Now I wanted to load some image dynamically to that image view.Fallowing is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
if (getAnySelectedRow == 0)
{
    //Load corresponding image
    NSLog(@"1 image loaded");
}
else if (getAnySelectedRow == 1)
{
    //Load corresponding image
    NSLog(@"2 image loaded");
}
else if (getAnySelectedRow == 2)
{
    //Load corresponding image
    NSLog(@"3 image loaded");
}

}
```

Note: Image view is already loaded on top of view controller.So I believe no need to init new image view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually quite simple. `UIImageView`, has an `image` property of type `UIImage`. All you have to do is create a `UIImage` object and then assign it to this property. If the image exists within your applications bundle, you can use +[UIImage imageNamed:]`.

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"];
```

Or to expand a little further..

```
if (getAnySelectedRow == 0) {
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"];
}else if (getAnySelectedRow == 1) {
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myOtherImageName"];
}else{
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myAnotherDifferentImageName"];
}
```

Comment: What is "myImageView"? Do I need to set property of UIImageView? How to write this?

Comment: @bapi You said you've already added an image view to your view? Have you already created a pointer to it?

Comment: Do I need to do like this: UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init]; Also, intelligence is not showing "UIImage" here: [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"]; How to do this?? Could you please be more clear?

Comment: @bapi Correct, Create an instance of UIImageView like that, be sure to set its `frame` property, and add it as a subview of your main view.

Answer (score 0):

x, y are the position the image view located, 
 width and height are the size of the ImageView

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"];
```